# what is the best way to convert a date & time given in certain timeZone to UTC in java

Tags: java, date

Example:
2021-07-26T12:06:00.000+0400 -> 2021-07-26T08:06:00.000UTC

I know I can do it manually but I was wondering if there any libraries that already offer this feature

Comment: Just use the ZonedDatetime Api, you don't need external libraries for that, you will have to write the same code and without using external libraries you have one source less of errors and maintainance

Comment: Should be closed as duplicate. Please refer this thread for more eloborate answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting ISO 8601-compliant String to java.util.Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso-8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date)

Answer (score 1):

No need to introduce a new third-party dependency here.

Simply use Java 8's `ZonedDateTime` to perform exactly what you are looking for:-

```
// Define your date & date format.
String dateFormat = "dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss a";
String dateString = "26-7-2021 12:20:00 PM";
LocalDateTime localTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat));

// Convert between time zones
ZonedDateTime newYorkTime = localTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
ZonedDateTime londonTime = localTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
```

You can find the Java API documentation & some more detailed examples [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

Comment: The format here does not match the Question’s format.